# What changes causes an ABI breaking in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, compatibility, abi

When the C++ standardization committee investigates modifications of the STL, a large attention is taken to not introduce ABI breaking changes.

What causes ABI breaking and what do not introduce ABI breaking in C++ ? ((link to courses or document focused on that are welcome)

Comment: Have you got a reference for the fact you state in the first paragraph? It seems a bit odd to me. I don't see why a library is concerned with the ABI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there's "[library] ABI" and "the ABI". The first can be an exposed binary interface (e.g. a C++ shared library). The second usually refers to the implementation defined code generation details of a compiler/platform/version/architecture/flags combination. The first depends on the second, but you can have a "library ABI that is portably stable"

Comment: @sehe Neither of which seem to be related to STL standards

Comment: Well, the library parts of the standard _are_ a library, see my edit ^

Comment: Some library vendors try to maintain a consisitent "library ABI", like libstdc++. This means that containers like `vector` always consist of the same data members. So the container interface may change, but only in ways that something compiled with an older version of the library can be linked against something new (despite this being formally UB). A breaking change would be something like adding an O(1) `size()` implementation to `std::list`. Other vendors never do this, e.g. Microsoft says they break compatibility with *every* release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although there is no common ABI, the standard committee *does* listen to vendor raising concerns about ABI breakage being reported by some vendors. Whether the concerns stop a change from being made depends on what is being changed.

For the standard library the primary issues causing potential ABI breakage are those which change the layout of a class or a class template or the changing the behavior of typically inlined functions. Most of the time the issues can be resolved by a slightly different formulation or by moving functionality a bit around.

For C++11 I remember ABI related discussions about `std::list<...>::size()` being made constant time and a COW implementation for `std::basic_string<...>` being prohibited. For the list issue the problem wasn't that because most implementations already used a constant time size anyway and the few which didn't couldn't make a strong enough case. For `std::basic_string<...>` the ABI for COW implementations was broken because the drawback of not making data race guarantees for different string objects was just not acceptable.

For some of the proposals which were brought forward, e.g., the idea of mandating a stack trace for `std::exception`s which would break everybody's exception ABI, the ABI breakage is pretty much a killer argument. Although changes which mandate ABI breaking changes are sometimes introduced, the case has to be argued a lot stronger than changes which don't affect anything: unless the benefit of the change outweights the reported potential of breaking some vendor's ABI it won't be done. In some contentious cases the implementers went back and investigated if there is a chance to implement a potentially slight inefficient version for backward compatibility.

The issue with ABIs is that there are definitely companies who will complain loudly if they can't use their old libraries with the new compilers. In some cases the vendors provide switches to support them but, e.g., `std::string` is baked into too many libraries that it would just be changed.